# open a particular type of file using input of type="file" in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to open a file using `<input type="file" ...>` and display it as text. I want the dialog box that pops up to open the file to show a particular extension of the file like ".txt" or ".jpg" instead of "All Files". how can I do that using javascript alone?

Comment: I think you can do thhat with accept attribute of input element.

Comment: I checked but accept just specifies if you want to use audio, video or image files etc. you cannot specify the extension of the file being selected. Thanks for the help though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `accept` attribute in the input:

```
<input type="file" accept=".txt,.jpg">
```

For more info, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input).